# How do I stop text running off screen and breaking layout without using CSS word-break property?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a comment section on my site where if the user presses and holds down a key like:

"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

The comment goes off the screen and breaks out of the layout. A solution is this:

```
.comment {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

But unfortunately, this breaks all comments even normal ones like this:

```
I just came here to say tha
t the quick brown fox jumped ov
er the lazy dog.
```

How do I fix the first issue without causing the second?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

css

```
.breaking{    
    width:500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nbafbacL/